# Weak derivative of extended function

Tags: analysis, weak-derivatives

Let a locally integrable  function $u: D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has weak derivative $Du$
and let $K:=\operatorname{supp} u \subset D$.

Let's define $v(x)=u(x)$ on $D$ and $v(x)=0$ on $\mathbb R^n \setminus D$.

Is it then $Dv=Du$ on $D$ and $Dv=0$ on $\mathbb R^n \setminus D$ ?

Comment: to clarify things: is $K$ closed in $\mathbb R^n$, or just in $D$? (in the first case the answer is yes, in the second there are easy counter-examples)

Comment: $K$ is compact.

Comment: Then yes. You can use the fact that there is a smooth function $\phi$ on $\mathbb R^n$ with support in $D$, such that $\phi=1$ in an open neighbourhood of $K$. Then you decompose any test function $f$  as $\phi f+ (1-\phi) f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comments:

Yes. You can use the fact that there is a smooth function ϕ on $R^n$ with support in D, such that ϕ=1 in an open neighbourhood of K. Then you decompose any test function f as ϕf+(1−ϕ)f.